# a variation of combineLatest that completes when the first of the observables passed as parameters completes

Tags: rxjs, reactive-programming

`combineLatest` operator returns an Observable that completes when all of the observables passed in as parameters to `combineLatest` complete.

Is there a way to create an Observable that behaves as the one returned by `combineLatest` with the only difference that it completes when the **first** of the Observables passed as parameters complete?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yep, you can; you can do something like this:

```js
function combineLatestUntilFirstComplete(...args) {
  const shared = args.map(a => a.share());
  return Rx.Observable
    .combineLatest(...shared)
    .takeUntil(Rx.Observable.merge(...shared.map(s => s.last())));
}

const a = Rx.Observable.interval(100).map(index => `a${index}`).take(5);
const b = Rx.Observable.interval(200).map(index => `b${index}`).take(5);

combineLatestUntilFirstComplete(a, b).subscribe(
  value => console.log(JSON.stringify(value)),
  error => console.error(error),
  () => console.log("complete")
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@5/bundles/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

The implementation takes values from the observable returned from the internal call to `combineLatest` until one of the source observables emits its last value.

Note that the source observables are shared, so that the subscriptions due to the `takeUntil` call don't effect secondary subscriptions to cold source observables.

Comment: Beat me to it while writing my answer ;-)

Answer (score 3):

```js
const a = Rx.Observable.interval(400).share();
const b = Rx.Observable.interval(600).share();
const c = Rx.Observable.interval(1000).take(3).share();

const combined = Rx.Observable.combineLatest(a, b, c)
  .takeUntil(
    Rx.Observable.merge(
      a.ignoreElements().concat(Rx.Observable.of('fin-a')).do(console.log),
      b.ignoreElements().concat(Rx.Observable.of('fin-b')).do(console.log),
      c.ignoreElements().concat(Rx.Observable.of('fin-c')).do(console.log)
    )
  );

combined
  .subscribe(console.log);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.5.10/Rx.js"></script>
```

You need to `.share()` the input observables because you need them twice, once for the `.combineLatest()` and once for the `.takeUntil` to complete your observable stream.

I used the `.ignoreElements()`  in the `.takeUntil` to ignore any values and only when the source stream (either `a`,`b`, or `c`) complete `.concat` a 'final' message to it to signal to the `.takeUntil` to complete our subscription to the `.combineLatest`. This also works if either `a,b,c` do not emit any values.

Comment: Really like this solution thanks !